# Why is `conda install jupyter` installing jupyter-lab?

Tags: jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I create a virtual environment using `conda` and install `jupyter` (on macOS). I can open JupyterLab using both `jupyter-lab` and `jupyter lab`.

The paths to `jupyter` and `jupyter-lab` are:

```
$ where jupyter
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/test1/bin/jupyter

$ where jupyter-lab
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/test1/bin/jupyter-lab
```

Why is `jupyter-lab` being installed? It seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to only affect recent builds in the `anaconda` (`defaults`) channel ([see files](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter/files)). Narrowly, the "why" is because the Anaconda Inc. developers changed the recipe to require `jupyterlab` starting with build number 8 (from about 8 months ago). Prior to this it was not included.

If you want a rationale for why this change was made, then file an Issue on [the `anaconda-issues` repository](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues).

Note that the Conda Forge version does not install `jupyterlab`.